# Jenkins Job Builder / JJB "wrappers" don't have any effect on generated jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I'm currently trying to realize job timeouts, etc vi "wrappers" as described in the [docs](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/wrappers.html?highlight=timeout#wrappers.timeout) and [some examples](https://gist.github.com/vickychijwani/12a5920a0c94965aec6a8e607d597042).

Regardless whether I apply wrappers directly on jobs or on job templates or defaults, I can't see any effect on the generated XML.

There is some [bug report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517279/jenkins-job-builder-wrappers-not-being-realized) from a couple of years ago but despite it sounds quite similar I think the solution does not apply for me since the report is Jenkins specific but my generated config does not contain a `<buildWrappers>` section at all!

For example the following YAML should generate a timeout section:

```yaml
- job:
    name: bla
    project-type: "pipeline"
    dsl: |
      sh("hello world")
    wrappers:
      - timeout:
          timeout-var: 'BUILD_TIMEOUT'
          fail: true
          elastic-percentage: 150
          elastic-default-timeout: 90
          type: elastic
```

Generated output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<flow-definition plugin="workflow-job">
  <definition class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition" plugin="workflow-cps">
    <script>sh(&quot;hello world&quot;)
</script>
    <sandbox>false</sandbox>
  </definition>
  <actions/>
  <description>&lt;!-- Managed by Jenkins Job Builder --&gt;</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.DisableConcurrentBuildsJobProperty/>
  </properties>
</flow-definition>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm using `jenkins-job-builder` v3.12.0 on Python 3.9

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it

```
    def gen_xml(self, xml_parent, data):
        if data.get("project-type", "freestyle") == "pipeline":
            logger.debug("Build wrappers skipped for Pipeline job")
            return
```

Looks like the documentation just didn't mention that wrappers don't work for the only job type I'm using :)

Comment: For anyone finding this who is using the `job-dsl` plugin instead, it seems a similar thing is the case: `wrappers` is not supported (https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.wrappers only applies to `job`/`freeStyleJob` but not `pipelineJob`/`multibranchPipelineJob`; see also https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/e6d655dd5b2874f56af8bf4b99a4d622b752bb98/docs/Migration.md?plain=1#L136-L167)